# Unit test Javascript with HTML context

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm currently writing a javascript game module that takes the following parameter as constructor argument:

```
{
  gameId : "string for unique game id",
  cssSelector: "selector for target (used to initialze game)"
 }
```

**I have found a way to get around this, see new comment below**

I have a pretty good test coverage on everything else, but I can't figure out how to write the following Jasmine test:

```
describe("Initialization of game", function() {
        it("Should throw expection if css selector is not found", function() {

           // what goes here?

            //negative scenario
           expect(function(){
                          var game = new Game({gameId : '1', cssSelector : "#not-found"});
                        }).toThrow("Cannot find the element corresponding to cssSelector");

          //positive senario
           expect(function(){
                          var game = new Game({gameId : '1', cssSelector : "#found"});
                        }).not.toThrow("Cannot find the element corresponding to cssSelector");
        });
```

**"Solution"**
I say "solution", because it feels a bit like a hack to get around this. I use the fact that the test is run in HTML and that I can manipulate the environment. So what I did was:

1. In the negative scenario, use a specifier that is not found. The first expectation will then not fail.
2. In between on the positive and negative test case, I used jQuerys .append() method to add a div with id "found" to the body

That's it!

Comment: the selector itself is a string. What are you using to select DOM element? jQuery,pure js,...

Comment: the module itself is dependent on jQuery, so I'll just select the element like '$(cssSelector)'. Have not heard about jQuery.pure.js -- I'll check if out to see if solves my problem - thanks!

Comment: no I've meant just js no framework

Comment: right, then the answer is: jQuery

Answer (score 1):

If you need more in depth DOM testing, Jasmine won't do it alone.

For a simple DOM requirements and single test, you can continue doing what you're doing.

For simple, but repeated tests, use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to set up and destroy the DOM elements you need during testing.

For anything but the most simple DOM tests, you could use something like: https://github.com/jeffwatkins/jasmine-dom to extend Jasmine in to the DOM.

Comment: jasmine-dom is what I was looking for. I still don't find it elegant, but it will definityly do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are missing a `);` after the `"#not-found"}`?

Comment: thanks for the post, sorry that's not the problem though -- I removed some code to get it more clear what I'm trying to do and the ); disappeared in that process.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery this will work.
If there's such DOM node it will have length greater than 0.

```
var exists = $('cssSelector').length > 0;
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I ended up using. however, I needed one more thing to get everything right -- I've updated my post with that.

Comment: I really don't get it, maybe you could be more specific